# Linden Scripting Language Post to PHP

Tags: linden-scripting-language

When I send a request from a [Linden Scripting Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linden_Scripting_Language) script to PHP with [LlHTTPRequest](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlHTTPRequest) I don’t get the values in PHP:

Example: ( LSL )

```
if(group_invite == "yes")
{

    list agents = llParseString2List(this_agent_name, [" "], []);

    string params = llDumpList2String([
        "firstname=" + llList2String(agents, 0),
        "lastname=" + llList2String(agents, 1)],
        "&");

    llHTTPRequest(
        "http://mysite/post-page.php",
        [HTTP_METHOD,"POST"],
        params);
}
```

I never get `firstname` and `lastname` values.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linden_Scripting_Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit arguments in that format in a POST request, your request must have the `Content-Type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
llHttpRequest(
    "http://example.com/post-page.php",
    [HTTP_METHOD, "POST", HTTP_MIMETYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
    params);
```